# Finding a running Difference in Columns with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, difference

I am trying to get the following result:

```
     HOUR  Throughput     Difference
       0           298          0
       1           209         -89
       6           1          -208
       7           8            -7
       8            9           1
       9           175          166
       10         223        and so on
       11         260
       12         246
       13         195
       14         170
       15         230
       16         200
       17         301
       18         316
       19         282
       20         293
       21         281
       22         175
       23         244
```

The sql statement i currently have is

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    HOUR(p_datetime) as HOUR,
    Count(p_type) as Throughput
    FROM
    product_log
    WHERE
    DATE(p_datetime) = '2013-11-30' AND
    p_type='STACK'
    GROUP BY HOUR;
```

I have been trying for a while now and cannot find a solution This is done in mysql.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT hour, throughput, difference
  FROM
(
  SELECT hour, throughput, 
         throughput - @p difference, @p := throughput
    FROM
  (
    SELECT HOUR(p_datetime) hour,
           COUNT(*) throughput
      FROM product_log l
     WHERE p_datetime >= '2013-11-30'
       AND p_datetime < '2013-11-31'
       AND p_type = 'stack'
     GROUP BY HOUR(p_datetime)
  ) a CROSS JOIN (SELECT @p := 0) i
) b
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c5f71/3)** demo

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I'm a little confused by the cross join and the nested selects, can you explain a little of it? thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :). `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @p := 0) i` just makes sure that a session variable `@p` is initialized with the value of `0`; innermost select produces aggregated and ordered resultset, then in outer select we calculate the difference as current value of `throughput - @p` and after that assign to `@p` a current value of `throughput` thus making available a previous value for next row. In the outermost select we just trim (not selecting) a 'collateral' column that produced by assignment `@p := throughput`.